# Calculate accuracy for trivia game

Tags: algorithm, probability

Say you have a game that gives the player a series of true or false questions.  The player answers them and the program remembers the answer history.

The history is just an array of booleans that show whether the player was correct, with the new questions inserted at the start of the array.

What is the best way to determine the current player performance?

You could take the average error rate (say 1 error every 10 questions).  But that punishes the player for mistakes that happened long ago.

You can add a kind of damping so that old errors have less 'power' as time goes by.  Basically an exponential weighted moving average.

I've tried those kinds of methods and they work well.  I tried researching bayesian networks but they don't seem to apply here.  They only seem useful for cases where you relations between multiple aspects.  In this case there is only 1 thing: 'odds of player being correct'.

Could anyone suggest a good way for finding a 'player performance' value, aka the probability of a player being correct on the next turn?

Comment: There is no "best way" if you don't define what you mean by "good". If you have found something that works as you like it, go with it.

Comment: They work ok but I wonder if there's something that will predict player's skill more accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach so far is good, but there is one way to significantly improve the player's predicted performance on the next question. The idea is to assign a skill rating to each player, and a difficulty rating to each question using the [ELO rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system).

You may be familiar with ELO ratings to predict the outcome of a match between two players in a game, but player vs. trivia question is just as valid. In fact the popular chess problem site [chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com/) uses this exact system.

After a player answers a question the player's and the question's ratings are updated accordingly based on their previous ratings, their K-factors, and whether the player got the question right or wrong. A right answer is like the player winning, and a wrong answer is like the question winning.

The player's predicted performance on the next question is given by the formula:

```
P(right answer) = 1/(1+10^((R_q-R_p)/400))
```

Where `R_q` is the question rating, and `R_p` is the player rating.

This system should address all of your concerns, including weighting older answers less - which is handled by the K-factor.

It also takes into the account the difficulty of the question, which should be a big factor in estimating whether the player will answer it correctly.

As an added bonus, it helps you select questions of appropriate difficulty for a given user.

Comment: Really interesting solution thanks.  I managed to find "rule of succession" which uses quite a simple bayesian formula for now, but will definitely look into ELO when adding some advanced functionality to the game.